# The source code for accent commands

Tags: accents, source, code

I'm using LaTeX on Ubuntu, it calls **TeX Live** here. I'm interested to see  source code of accent commands behavior. Where can I find it?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks a lot, Martin, for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`source2e.pdf`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf). Besides downloading, you could write

```
texdoc source2e
```

at the command prompt

This file contains the commented LaTeX sources. Use the PDF reader search feature for `accent` or `\DeclareTextAccent` and `\DeclareTextCommand`.